# How do I run performance tests for a unity3D - webGL implementation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a website running a unity3D - webGL application, the website is crashing when multiple users try connect simultaneously.

I want to create performance tests, so I can test my websites before releasing them, my first approach was with Jmeter with BlazeMeter to record the server interaction, unsuccessfully, only part of the interactions were saved.

The test I want to implement is very simple

1. Load the webpage
   2.Hit some buttons
2. enter a username and email
3. Click some buttons inside webgl

Do you have any suggestion?
Is Jmeter the correct tool for what I am trying to implement?

Comment: WebGL is running on the client, not the server. So some other component is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from adding [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener which allows you inspecting requests and responses details, this way you will be able to see what exactly your JMeter test is doing and which is the problematic request which doesn't properly do its job.

You can also use a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) in order to compare the outgoing traffic from the real browser and JMeter, given you will be sending the same requests (apart from some dynamic parameters which needs to be [correlated](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter/)) you should be getting the same responses, once JMeter's network footprint will match the real browser you should be good to proceed with the stress testing of your sites.